# How to increment a value inside a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I am looking to do the following within a generator that iterates through a ~5GB file:

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter()
lines_as_list = (line.strip().split('|') for line in open('file-00000-of-00001.csv'))
header = next(lines_as_list)
item_data = (dict(zip(header, data)) for data in lines_as_list)
totals_per_country = (c[item['country']]+=1 for item in item_data)
```

This of course fails due to trying to assign a value within the comprehension. What would be the suggested way to do this in a generator (without using a for loop or library such as pandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `Counter` as

```
c = Counter(item['country']for item in item_data)
```

and it’s now counted your countries up.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass a generator of the countries to the `Counter`, as that takes an iterable. For example:

```
>>> countries = (item['country'] for item in item_data)
>>> totals_per_country = Counter(countries) # not a generator, evaluates immediately
>>> totals_per_country.most_common(5)
[('US', 299072), ('CA', 183927), ('GB', 150242), ('AU', 131295), ('DE', 100611)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new Walrus operator in Python 3.8

```py
(c[item['country']]:=c[item['country']]+1 for item in item_data)
```

This allows you to do assignments an expression, making it syntactically legal in places it otherwise is not, such as a comprehension